# Equation of an ellipse using eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In a paper, I work in, gives that $x=(x_1, x_2)$ is a vector of elements and have $M=(m_1, m_2)$ eigenvalues and $u={u_1, u_2}$ are eigenvectors of a matrix $W$, then it mentioned that the equation of ellipse is giving by
 $$(x, W^{-1}x)= a,\quad\text{(1)}$$
 where $a$ is a specific value. In another line it of the same paper, it said that for coordinates 
 $$z_1=(x, u_1)\;\text{and}\;z_2=(x,u_2)\quad\text{(2)}$$
 the equation of ellipse in that standard for is
 $$(z_1^2/m_1) + (z_2^2/m_2)=a.\quad\text{(3)}$$

The question is: what do equations $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ mean since I need to plot the equation of the ellipse using any of equations $\text{(1)}$ or $\text{(3)}$ ?
Thanks

Comment: Very hard to read what you wrote. Please read the instructions to write mathematics in this site.

Comment: The notation in $(2)$ is meaningless in this context. Did you copy faithfully ?

Comment: It is better to let the OP to correct his own question, in particular when it comes so messy and unclear.

Comment: Does $(\cdot,\cdot)$ stand for scalar product?

Comment: < , > would be better...

Answer (score 1):

By the given Eigen elements,

$$Wu_1=m_1u_1,\\Wu_2=m_2u_2$$ and multipying by the inverse,

$$W^{-1}u_1=\frac1{m_1}u_1,\\W^{-1}u_2=\frac1{m_2}u_2.$$

Now assuming that

$$x=z_1u_1+z_2u_2,$$ where $$z_1=<x,u_1>,\\z_2=<x,u_2>,$$ we have

$$<x,W^{-1}x>=<z_1u_1+z_2u_2,\frac{z_1}{m_1}u_1+\frac{z_2}{m_2}u_2>=\frac{z_1^2}{m_1}+\frac{z_2^2}{m_2},$$ by (assumed) orthonormality of $u_1,u_2$.

This doesn't match the given equation (3), which is dubious.

Comment: you're right, equation (3) is z1^2/m1+z2^2/m2=a... it means that brackets (..) are the product. Thanks a lot for your help